# How do I see what output options are available in my proc?

Tags: sas

Running complex procs such as `PROC REG` or `PROC GLM`, there are often tables that are produced in the output window describing the results of the regression, in addition to the output datasets produced using `OUT` or `OUTPUT` options.

How can I output those tables to SAS datasets?

For example, given the first SAS example in PROC REG (on the [documentation page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect054.htm)), how can I output the Goodness of Fit Statistics (such as the R-Squared)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to identify possible output datasets, SAS provides the [`ods trace`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/61723/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002233618.htm) statement.  This asks SAS to write to the log the name (and some details) of each data table it writes to the output.  In most cases, this can be saved to a dataset via [`ods output`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/61723/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002233313.htm).

For example, in the SAS example referred to in the question, you could write:

```
ods trace on; 
    proc reg data=baseball;
       id name team league;
       model logSalary = no_hits no_runs no_rbi no_bb yr_major cr_hits;
    run;
ods trace off;
```

That would report in the log that "FitStatistics" is the name of the output object you want.  Then you write:

```
ods output FitStatistics=fitds;
proc reg data=baseball;
   id name team league;
   model logSalary = no_hits no_runs no_rbi no_bb yr_major cr_hits;
run;
```

and it will output the `fitds` dataset.

ODS Trace is only needed for the purpose of determining the name of the table of course - once you know the name of the table you need, you can simply use that name with `ods output` in the future.

You also frequently can find the list of the table names in the documentation; for example, PROC REG places them [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect051.htm).

ODS Output may be placed any location before the `run` statement (as it is a global statement); a common location is immediately before `run`.  My personal preference is to put it before the `proc` as it is a global statement, but [there is some disagreement with that approach](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/04/08/pointcounterpoint-ods-select.html).